# Add n columns between every column for a 2d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to create a function that adds n columns between every existing column of a 2d numpy array. The values of the additional columns doesn't really matter, it could be zeros or nans. I know I can add the columns one at the time using a for loop but since I'm working with large arrays, I was wondering if there is a better way to do it.

For example, let's say I have

```
import numpy as np
n = 3
a = np.array([
[1, 2, 3],
[4, 5, 6],
[7, 8, 9]])
```

The function `b = add_intra_columns(a, n)` would return the following output:

```
np.array([
[1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3],
[4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 6],
[7, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 9]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like

```
b = np.zeros((a.shape[0], a.shape[1] * (n + 1) - n))
b[:, ::n+1] = a
```

Comment: You can do `b[:,::n+1] = a` to avoid looping :)